# How to get unique (not vice-versa) fields on MySQL

Tags: mysql

The title may be misleading but i don't know how to formulate it better.

Suppose i have these rows on my MySQL table:

table1:

```
id    column1    column2
1     1          2
2     1          3  
3     2          1
4     3          4
```

I have written a query to retrieve data that have similar vice-versa values on columns column1 and column2 (id: 1 & id: 3), but I'm having trouble querying over data that don't have similar vice-versa rows (id: 2 & id: 4) or that are sort of unique.

EDIT: The query i've used to get vice-versa rows

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2
ON (t1.column1 = t2.column2 AND t1.column2 = t2.column1);
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the query you've written on obtaining the similar values? If this is correct thenyou can use the same query to get the result of the rows.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Hi, i've edited the original question and added the query

Answer (score 1):

You could use exists logic here:

```
SELECT id, column1, column2
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE LEAST(t2.column1, t2.column2) = LEAST(t1.column1, t1.column2) AND
                        GREATEST(t2.column1, t2.column2) = GREATEST(t1.column1, t1.column2));
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply. How could I use this query if the data are strings instead of integers?

Comment: ... it should for strings as well, but keep in mind that `LEAST` and `GREATEST` applied to text will use lexicographic sorting, not numerical sorting.  That is, `'2'` is greater than `'12'`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use your query in the `WHERE` clause to filter out similar rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE (column1, column2) NOT IN
   (SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2 
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table1 t2
       ON t1.column1 = t2.column2 AND t1.column2 = t2.column1)
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f2c54/2)

Comment: Thank you, I've already tried to go for a similar approach but failed to come up with the right syntax at the WHERE (column1, column2) clause.